# Get and replace text containing :: inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I use jquery to find ::123:: , get 123 out(as an id) then change it into an image inside a div that has many lines.

The div:

```
<div id="msg">
 <ul>
   <li class="message">hello</li>
   <li class="message">123</li>
   <li class="message">thrid line ::123::</li>
   <li class="message">yes</li>
   <li class="message">sure</li>
   <li class="message">fourth line ::123::</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Results would be:

```
<div id="msg">
 <ul>
   <li class="message">hello</li>
   <li class="message">123</li>
   <li class="message">thrid line <img src="image?id=123"></li>
   <li class="message">yes</li>
   <li class="message">sure</li>
   <li class="message">fourth line <img src="image?id=123"></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

P/S the contents in the lines are just example.

How can I do this?

Comment: use `regex` match and replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will replace any number you have inside double colons with a related `<img>` tag:

```
$('.message').each(function() {
    $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/::([^:]+)::/g,'<img src="image?id=$1">') );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/khk4a/

You might reconsider the HTML replacement logic here, the source would be pretty awkward for a search engine or text reader. Try using another hook, f.ex an empty `<i>` with a class or data attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Try this bellow code.

```
$("li.message").each(function()
{
    var newText = $(this).text().replace(/::123::/g, '<img src="image?id=123">');
    $(this).text(newText);
 });
```

Comment: I think you need to use `.html()` instead of `.text()` to insert the IMG tag without jQuery escaping the string.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/5ZAvK/3/

You'd probably want to generalize it to work with any number.

EDIT: Updated to take the number found in the regex and insert it into the link using `$1`.

EDIT 2: Updated again to work with any number.

Comment: Updated again to work for any number. I figured I'd let the OP do some work generalizing it but, changed it.

Answer (score 1):

I think jquery can solve that easily [check this](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the underlying html structure, I would recommend you replace **::123::** with another blank html element, with a particular class. For example,

```
<li class="message">thrid line ::123::</li>
```

would then be

```
<li class="message">thrid line <span class='replaceMe' data-key="myId"></span></li>
```

Then use jquery to replace the elements as follows

```
var replaceableElements = $('.replaceMe');
replaceableElements.each(function(){
    var me = $(this),
        myId = me.data('key');
    me.replaceWith('<img src=image?id="'+ myId +' />');
});
```